# music used in The Social Network AND Moneyball

Tags: soundtrack, the-social-network, moneyball

There is a song used in both movies, it occurs towards the beginning of each movie around the time that both parties make a "breakthrough".

In Moneyball, the music plays when Jonah Hill's character first moves to Oakland and starts doing his thing.

In The Social Network, I don't remember exactly, but I know it plays just as Mark Zuckerberg gets his grand idea and starts programming The Facebook.

The song is very soft, slow, and soothing. It gives positive feelings of "discovery", "creativity," "ingenuity."
Can you guys help me find this song?

Comment: Love this question! I'm at work so I can't pop in the "Social Network" DVD to check. But I'm interested in the answer too.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the song in Moneyball, here's the [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0m8K2Ktz6Q). I'm going to rewatch The Social Network to see if it plays at all like I suspected.

Comment: The song in The Social Network starts when he first gets home after the break up. It's the piano music around 7:45. I'm CERTAIN that the same piano music is in Moneyball.

Comment: It's the piano melody to "Hand Covers Bruise". Now I get to rewatch Moneyball, which I don't mind because it's my favorite movie.

Comment: According to all resources I can find, this song does not appear in the Social Network. Therefore, I'd advise you to edit your answer to report that and mark it as accepted - as there's no point in the question remaining open if the answer is the song isn't in both films.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's any overlap between the *Moneyball* and *The Social Network* soundtracks (according to IMDB and What-song). They were composed by different people (Trent Reznor and Atticus Ross for *The Social Network* and Mychael Danna for *Moneyball*) and don't share any non-original music. I would guess you're thinking of either Intriguing Possibilities from *The Social Network* or It Would Be Like This from *Moneyball*. If none of those are right, here's the [website](http://www.what-song.com/Movies/Soundtrack/1094/Moneyball) I used to look up the songs. It's incredibly useful, it gives a sentence long description of what's happening in the film as each song is played.

Answer (score -1):

Actually that piece of music isn't in "The Social Network" but it is in the movie "Room" during Jack's escape scene. You can YouTube it here:
Watch "This Will Destroy You - The Mighty Rio Grande" on YouTube

Answer (score -1):

Moneyball clip at 2:44 -

Social Network at 1:02 -

The background music is different, and the instrument is different, but the notes and spacing seems close to identical. Somebody bit somebody's stuff.